# When should HTTP 400 Bad Request be used as a response code?

Tags: httpresponse

According to Wikipedia, a response code of 400 indicates `The request cannot be fulfilled due to bad syntax.`

Is this the appropriate status code to return when invalid but syntactically correct data is given? If not, what is?

Answer (score 1):

I don't claim to be an expert, but let's compare what [the spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) says:

```
400 Bad Request - The request could not be understood by the server due 
to malformed syntax....
```

So the 400 seems to be specific to syntax errors.  Here's another one that looks better for when the syntax is good but the value isn't:

```
409 Conflict - The request could not be completed due to a conflict with 
the current state of the resource...
```

You'll want to read [the full description for 409](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.10) before deciding (it's much more lengthy), but this seems to be a better choice for the given scenario.  It says conflicts most likely would happen with PUT requests, but as I read it, it seems like it could apply any time an input variable is invalid.  This is what I think I'll use for the RESTful API I'm building.